# Es mejor usar App.config o Sqlconectionstring builder en mi conexion con sqlserver

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio-2017

Cual de las dos formas de conectarse a Sqlserver es mas segura, actualmente tengo la conexion en el app config de la manera siguiente,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
<configSections>
</configSections>
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="presentacion.Properties.Settings.Setting" connectionString="Data 
Source=DESKTOP-H2AUF0F\SQLEXPRESS01;Initial Catalog=Agencia2;Integrated Security=True"
        providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
<startup> 
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1" />
 </startup>
</configuration>
```

o debería hacer mi conexion de la manera siguiente

```
 SqlConnectionStringBuilder builder = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder();
    builder.DataSource = "(DESKTOP-H2AUF0F\SQLEXPRESS01)";
    builder.IntegratedSecurity = true;
    builder.InitialCatalog = "Agencia2";
```

gracias de antemano

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Definitivamente usar App.config ya que si te piden cambiar el servidor de Base de datos (me refiero a la ruta u otro servidor digamos una bd azure) Solo tienes que cambiar el .config de tu aplicación.

Y por seguridad se deja al encargado de IT a donde alojes la aplicación o también encriptar (haciendo una rutina) para que el  .config no pueda ser visto por nadie más.